# Why is the post form not running the requested route?

Tags: laravel, forms, post

I've got what appears to be a simple POST request to a route, but for some reason the method is not being processed.

web.php

```php
Route::get('/', [clockController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/', [clockController::class, 'timerTimezoneValue'])->name('timerTimezoneValue');
```

clockController.php

```php
class clockController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
    $timezoneData = timezones::get(['timezone_value', 'timezone_region', 'timezone_city']);
    $date = date("H:i");
    $timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
    $completeDate = $date . " " . $timezone;
    $city = true;
    return view('clockManagement/clockMain', compact('timezoneData', 'completeDate', 'city'));
    }

    public function timerTimezoneValue(Request $timezoneValue) {
    dd($timezoneValue->all());
    return view('clockManagement/clockMain', compact('timezoneData', 'completeDate', 'city'));
    }
}
```

Form:

```xml
<form method="post" action="{{route('timerTimezoneValue')}}">
    @csrf
    {{-- <label for="timezoneValue">Timezone</label> --}}
    <select id="TZValue" name="TZValue">
        @foreach ($timezoneData as $timezone)
        <option value="{{$timezone->timezone_value}}">{{$timezone->timezone_city}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Nu blet</button>
</form>
```

Basically the form is supposed to send a post request with option value to `timerTimezoneValue`, but the method is not opening.

Comment: what is happening when you press the submit button? 
you may check the network tap in the inspect element

Comment: What version of Laravel? Nothing in the logs? Have you tried `[\App\Http\Controllers\clockController::class, 'timerTimezoneValue']`?

Comment: After submitting, the default page opens as if the index method was processed. I'm using latest laravel version (8.42.1). Changing to `[\App\Http\Controllers\clockController::class, 'timerTimezoneValue']` got me an error. Here's the network screenshot: https://prnt.sc/13hbqg9

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by installing a fresh laravel framework and moving the controllers, views etc. Not sure what caused the issue but it's good now